# How to make doubles always contain a . character?

Tags: c#

I noticed my doubles contain different precision characters depending on regional settings.

For example:

`3,47` or `3.45`

How can I enforce the double should always contain a `.` precision character?

Problem is once I serialize the class containing this double to XML, it gets shipped to other systems expecting a standard result.

So after reading your responses (and thanks), do you guys recommend changing the property to a string, (making the replacements in a string), so that it serializes with the string value (not the double)?

Comment: On your last additional comment: don't use replacements on the string (what about the thousand separator? Or non-float numbers ending with a grammar-comma? You'll get into more trouble doing this later in the chaing, just use `InvariantCulture` the moment you transform to a string, or set `Application.CurrentCulture` to not bother at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to put the double to string using the Invariant Culture.

```
double d = 3.47;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 7):

You will need to format with the [InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx).

Note that the "." and "," formatting characters [are interpreted according to the culture settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierPt).

Comment: +1. Yeap- more specifically the code creating the XML should be running under InvariantCulture.

Answer (score 2):

The double itself doesn't include a "." or a ",", only the print out of the representation does. You can read up on custom formats [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

[Update according to OP]
I don't know exactly what your design looks like, but it would probably be smart to create a string property on your DTO, which would output the formatted string of your double, and then mark your double property as not serializable.

Answer (score 2):

This little tutorial will be the answer you need, I expect:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0440__I18N-Internationalization/Parsingnumberswithcultureinvariantparsing.htm

```
double.Parse(numberString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to do this for all numbers in your current applicaton, you can use the following to set it application-wide (new threads will inherit this setting):

```
// use this statement to force the default:
Application.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string s = myNumber.ToString();

// for one number you have to remember to use:
string s = myNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note: by default, your application, whether ASP.NET or WinForms, will use the culture settings of the system it is running on (in ASP.NET, you can set the culture globally in the `web.config`).